# Vim: Archiving text selections into other file

Tags: vim, vimwiki

I'd like to create a command and bindings for appending a selected piece of text into another file located next to it with a timestamp.
I've put some scraps together from other posts, yet I barely know what I am doing and I am not getting what I expect.

```
fun! MoveSelectedLinesToFile(filename)
    exec "'<,'>w! >>" . a:filename
    norm gvd
endfunc

fun! ArchiveSelectedLinesToFile(filename)
  call writefile( ["[" . strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") . "]"], a:filename, "a" )
  call MoveSelectedLinesToFile(a:filename)
  call writefile( ["",""], a:filename, "a" )
endfunc

vnoremap a :call ArchiveSelectedLinesToFile(expand('%:p') . '.arc.md')<CR>
```

using this on a sequence of lines 4-6 of this content:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The archive file shows:

```
[2022-09-19 14:52:10]


[2022-09-19 14:52:10]
```

while it should show

```
[2022-09-19 14:52:10]
4
5
6
```

and the source file was altered to

```
1
2
3
8
9
```

which is one line to much as 7 was wrongfully taken.
I am on Windows, if that means anything.

Q:

1. I am getting E16 invalid range errors for all 3 lines of `ArchiveSelectedLinesToFile`. Where from there exactly? And why?
2. Is there a way to maybe just construct a block of text and append that instead of adding the different bits, like the timestamp and the whitespace one by one? Make it one coherent operation? Maybe only bother the piping-mechanism once?
3. Why is this so inconsistent? Sometimes for one triggering I get 2 timestamps with no payload into the other file and once it even worked fine.
4. Is there some easier way of doing archiving in this or a similar way?

I am aware that none of this is probably as clean as it could be, yet I do not know better as of now. Improvement suggestions of form are appreciated.

Background:
I recently started using [VimWiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki) for taking notes, including my TODOs, my call-stack if you will. I have one main TODO file, however large tasks warrant their own file.
Now whenever I am done with a TODO I might have put more notes under the heading of that TODO since its inception, holding valuable information for future me.
Without going to the length of creating an extra wiki entry for the topic, traditionally I just deleted the lines, I've come to think it would be neat to archive most of them away instead. I think using Version Control for this is overkill.
By putting those contents into another file with a timestamp this acts as a sort of history. Further I could still choose between archiving and deleting to decide what might be relevant further and what's not.

Comment: Version control doesn't sound overkill to me.

Comment: @romainl It seems to me the wrong tool in this case. You'd have to check in after basically every little change or so spontaneously that it's inautomatic and inconsistent. VC makes sense for the whole VimWiki as a repository of knowledge in general, after one writes an article, yet not for the TODOs, as in them I change things constantly, while I am actually doing something else. I do not want to divert more attention from my task, just to check in one small note i made, even if I could make another shortcut for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help writefile()` takes a list as first argument so a better strategy would be  to build the list first, with timestamp and all, and then use a single `writefile()`.

For that, you need to start by handling ranges properly. When you call a function defined like this over a range, the function is called for each line:

```
function! Foo()
    echo line('.')
endfunction
:4,6call Foo()
4
5
6
```

which is totally fine if that's your goal, but this is not the case here. You want your function to be called *once*, so you need to define it with the `range` argument:

```
function! Foo() range
    echo line('.')
endfunction
:4,6call Foo()
4
```

which allows you to handle the range yourself, within the function:

```
function! Foo() range
    echo a:firstline
    echo a:lastline
endfunction
:4,6call Foo()
4
6
```

See `:help :func-range`.

**First**, generate a timestamp:

```
function! ArchiveSelectedLinesToFile() range
    let timestamp = '[' . strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') . ']'
endfunction
```

**Second**, store the selected lines in a variable:

```
function! ArchiveSelectedLinesToFile() range
    let timestamp = '[' . strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') . ']'
    let lines = getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)
endfunction
```

See `:help getline()`.

**Third**, put them together in a list:

```
function! ArchiveSelectedLinesToFile() range
    let timestamp = '[' . strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') . ']'
    let lines = getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)
    let archival_data = [timestamp] + lines
endfunction
```

See `:help list-concatenation`.

**Fourth**, write the list to the given file:

```
function! ArchiveSelectedLinesToFile(filename) range
    let timestamp = '[' . strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') . ']'
    let lines = getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)
    let archival_data = [timestamp] + lines
    call writefile(archival_data, a:filename, 'a')
endfunction
```

**Fifth**, delete the selected lines:

```
function! ArchiveSelectedLinesToFile(filename) range
    let timestamp = '[' . strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') . ']'
    let lines = getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)
    let archival_data = [timestamp] + lines
    call writefile(archival_data, a:filename, 'a')
    execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 'd _'
endfunction
```

See `:help :range`, `:help :d` and `:help "_`.

You are not done yet, though, because of all the text objects that start with `a`. This will cause timing issues so you will have to map your function call to a different key that is not the start of some command, motion, or mapping. Additionally, you might want to restrict your mapping to visual mode. Here is an example with `<F5>`, YMMV:

```
xnoremap <F5> :call ArchiveSelectedLinesToFile(expand('%:p') . '.arc.md')<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you. You not only solved my problem, but I learned a lot reading this. I suspected something happening line by line instead of being applied once, but had no idea what to do about that before. If I aim to do vimscripting more often I should also definitely take the time and do a tutorial/course somewhere to handle some basics, if I can find a good one.